# Regression F and t statistic

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, anova, linear

My understanding was that, to make a hypothesis test of a linear combination of regression parameters (e.g. of the type $\beta_1+2\beta_2=0$), you should use a decision rule of the form

$|T| = \left| \frac{\boldsymbol{a^T\hat\beta}}{s(\boldsymbol{a^T(Z^TZ)^{-1}a})^\frac{1}{2}} \right| > t_{n-k-1,\alpha/2}$ (1)

where $\boldsymbol{a}$ encodes the linear combination required (here $a=(1,2)^T$).

Now in the books (e.g. Rencher & Schaalje p205) I do not find this form but rather

$F = \frac{(\boldsymbol{a^T\hat\beta})^2}{s^2(\boldsymbol{a^T(Z^TZ)^{-1}a})} > F_{1,n-k-1,\alpha}$ (2)

I'm aware that the F-distribution with $\nu_1=1,\nu_2$ is equal to $t_{\nu=\nu_2}^2$. The problem comes when I start thinking about the left-handed side of this range. Namely, since the F-score can't be negative, how does it map to the negative half of the t-distribution which we would use for a hypothesis test like $\beta_1+2\beta_2<0$? Doesn't this lack of a negative half of the distribution affect the use of the test for right-tailed hypotheses (like $\beta_1+2\beta_2>0$) as well?

Comment: Hint: notice the "$\alpha/2$" instead of $\alpha$ for the t quantile.

Comment: Actually I put the decision boundaries in from my own understanding (they weren't found in any textbook). I can't see how they help with my problem (specifically, that the RHS of the universally-accepted equation, that for F, should be able to be negative - in which case, how can it be compared with the (always-positive) F statistic: I think this is the source of the confusion regarding how both F tests and T tests can be used equivalently here)? To be clear, it's not the two-tail case which troubles me so much as the left-tail case (which makes me worry I don't understand two-tail either).