The distribution followed by the number obtained by dividing coefficient a1 by the other coefficients a2 in multiple regression
Given the following multiple regression model.
$$
y\sim N(a_0+a_1x_1+a_2x_2,\sigma)
$$
where $y$ is the response variable, $N(\mu,\sigma)$ is the normal distribution following the mean as $\mu$ and standard deviation as $\sigma$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ is the explanatory variable and $a_1$ and $a_2$ is the coefficients.
I want to test whether the coefficient $a_1$ divided by $a_2$ of this regression model is significantly different compared to a certain number.
In this case, when the coefficient of the regression model is divided by the other coefficients, what distribution does the number ($\frac{a_2}{a_1}$) follow?

As discussed in posts on site already, rather than take the ratio, a test of the null that the ratio of two parameters is some specific number $c$ ($H_0: \frac{\beta_2}{\beta_1}=c$ against some alternative, presumably a two-sided/ inequality alternative) instead test the equivalent linear hypothesis $H_0: \beta_2-\beta_1 c = 0$ against the corresponding alternative.

Thank you for your answer.
If the degrees of freedom are large, the coefficients follow a normal distribution, so does this mean that the distribution of the coefficients divided by the coefficients will be a Cauchy distribution and not suitable for the test?
Could you please refer me to a page that would help me reject $H_0:\beta_2 - \beta_1c=0$. It seems to me that $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are not independent as long as they are in the same model. Please point out any errors due to lack of knowledge.

The corresponding estimates of $β_1$ and $β_2$, $\hat{β}_1$ and $\hat{β}_2$ are indeed dependent in general, but are multivariate normal under the usual assumptions, so $\hat{β}_1-c\hat{β}_1$ is normal. This is readily tested using standard methods (rather than having to make new ones). The general case is the general linear hypothesis test (an F test) but there's multiple ways to construct the test statistic for this specific kind that are either t-tests or F tests. The exact steps that are easiest depends on what your software provides, but it's possible in any decent stats program.

e.g. in R, one of the options is to use multcomp::glht. However, if I was doing it in something unhelpful like Excel I'd simply fit two models; one with the restriction under H0 set and one with it free and do the F test based off the change in sum of squares.

For both the t test and the F test the formulas are given in the question here:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445524/regression-f-and-t-statistic
(though what's $Z$ there is more usually written as $X$). The answer here covers
the case $c=1$, which only requires a small change to this case.
This search gets the general case of which yours is a very simple special case: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=general+linear+hypothesis+test

The same kind of search terms as a browser search gets a number of sets of notes on the topic.
Any regression text worth the name covers this stuff.

Thank you for your advice.
I could solve this problem by using multcomp::glht

I'm unsure if this is distinct enough to copy my comments as an answer or not. I was not able to find a close enough duplicate for it to VtC.
